# Ahead of time compilation — components

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am pretty new to Angular 5, and I have some questions about ahead of time compilation and components.

Is it possible to compile a component only? By default Angular 5 will compile the whole solution, but what I need is this:

Assuming I create a component called calendar. This component will have 3 files, an .scss file for style, a .ts file for code, and and .html file for html code.

My question: can I compile these as separate files so I will get: one .css file, one .js file and .html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of ahead-of-time compilation is to put them in one file and do type checking. So basically the answer is no.

But you can use the Typescript compiler (tsc) and the SCSS compiler to compile your typescript and your scss file.

If you want to use the Angular Compiler to compile the file you should install [ngc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/compiler-cli). You will need a projectspecific tsconfig.json, which depends on your specific use-case. The documentation for the compiler can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

Comment: Do you mean, that ahead-of-time compilation will create one single file with the style, javascript and html? That's fine also, even better? What this file will look like? What extension?

Comment: I didn't knew that. Can you show an example how the file will look like?